# Potential leak of an object allocated in dictionary allocation

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, ios4

`NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

(Value stored to 'dict' during its initialization is never read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't use 'dict'.
2. You don't release 'dict' after you're done with it. It is leaked because you used 'alloc' to create it, and you own it automatically and hence have to release it when you're done with it.

I suggest [learning how Memory Management works](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) on iOS/OS X before continuing further. This is **not** something you can ignore; you need to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably overwriting 'dict' later. Or you're just never reading it again. Most likely the former. Where else are you using 'dict'?